# how to register the activeX component(.dll) in 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, activex

i create the ActiveX control(.dll) using user control & register as COM component . it working fine in 32 bit OS . but when register the same activeX control in 64 bit os (window server 2008) it throws following exception

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file :////C:\Program Files\STPL\GlobActiveX.dll' or one of its dependencies. an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

i have used the following code to register the dll component

```
filepath=C:\Program Files \STPL\GlobActiveX.dll
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
            RegistrationServices regAsm = new RegistrationServices();
            bool bResult = regAsm.RegisterAssembly(asm, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
```

how to register the activeX component(.dll) in 64 bit OS?

i want to installed this activeX in 64 bit program files.I have install my winform application as setup 64 bit.i.e this setup will be installed in 64 bit platform . because i have used the one path.gcon file to working with my application when my activeX loaded then it take databse path from the my application installation path from the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\APPLICATION_NAME\LOCATION then from this location read the path.gcon file then start the activeX control

when i have register the activeX as x86 platform then it register successfully & stored into the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\wow6432Node. path.gcon can not read in activeX control.
How to register the ActiveX control in x64 platform?

Comment: Do you really have a space after `"Program Files"? If so, it probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: there is no space after Program Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dll is 32-bit, so exe must run in 32-bit mode.
In 64-bit Windows, .NET exe with Platform AnyCPU runs in 64-bit mode.
In 32-bit Windows, .NET exe with Platform AnyCPU runs in 32-bit mode.
I think you host exe is Platform AnyCPU, recompile it to Platform x86,
or use CorFlags.exe to change the exe, force 32-bit flag on.